# How to filter an ArrayBuffer of JsObject to remove items having a specific value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have the following variable in my play 2.3 app

```
private var messages = ArrayBuffer[JsObject]()
```

and I would like to remove all elements from messages that have a specific value of the key "message_id". My current implementation is the following

```
messages = messages.filterNot{item =>
    if ((item \ "message_id").as[Int] == myMessageId){
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

this works, but I am almost certain that I am missing a more elegant scala-like way to accomplish the same thing. What would be the idiomatic way to filter for a JsObject containing a specific key/value pair?

Comment: As a general point, you don't need the if/else - just use the condition directly `messages.filterNot{item =>(item \ "message_id").as[Int] == myMessageId}`. Ryan's answer is better for your specific context, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to do it, each variations of the ideas by Ryan and Paul.

First is to use the "verifying" method from [play.api.libs.json.ConstraintReads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.ConstraintReads) to refine the Reads transformer suggested by Ryan to only match a specific value:

```
val messageId = (__ \ "message_id").read[Int](verifying[Int](_ == 123))
messages = messages.filterNot{_.validate(messageId).isSuccess}
```

The second way is to select the field directly from the JsObject as suggested by Paul but use [asOpt[T]](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject) to ensure that an exception is not thrown if the key does not exist or the value is of the wrong type:

```
messages = messages.filterNot{x => (x \ "message_id").asOpt[Int] == Some(123)}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Play's `Reads` transformers.

```
val messageId = (__ \ "message_id").read[Int].filter(_ == myMessageId)

messages = messages.filter(_.validate(messageId).isSuccess)
```

This will also handle the case where `message_id` doesn't exist or somehow isn't an int though depending on your use case you may not want to silently discard that error.

Comment: This seems like a good way to filter for all JsObjects that have an integer value for that key but how can I use this pattern to filter for a specific value of that key? Ex: I want to remove all JsObjects from the ArrayBuffer containing {"message_id" => 1} but not {"message_id" => 2}.

Comment: Is there any real difference between using filter(_ == 123) and using (verifying[Int](_ == 123)) as in my solution below?